# Running time of program

Tags: c++

The program listed below outputs 0 on the screen. Why? Does it mean that my computer is fast or something is wrong in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int j=0;
    clock_t start=clock();
     for (int i=0;i<22220;i++){
         i++;
         j++;
         j+=i;
        // sleep(10);
     }

     clock_t final=clock()-start;
     cout<<final/ (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you doing i++ in the for-loop iterator section and in the body? and why j++ and j+=i?

Comment: and have you tried printing out just start and final to see what they show?

Comment: it just i want to take some time to execute these statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `clock()` doesn't return *wall clock* time, instead it has to do with the processing time in which sleep does nothing practically(it yields control to the operating system).

Try to remove sleep, and increase the loop count.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about this, you might want to examine the outputted assembly code, but since neither i nor j are actually used in the rest of the program, the compiler might not generate any code for those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>

SYSTEMTIME startTime;
GetSystemTime(&startTime);
WORD startmillis = (startTime.wSecond * 1000) + startTime.wMilliseconds;

// Do some stuff

SYSTEMTIME endTime;
GetSystemTime(&endTime);
WORD endmillis = (endTime.wSecond * 1000) + endTime.wMilliseconds;

WORD millis = startmillis - endmillis ;
```